# write csv into s3 having creds for being directly inside bucket

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to save a csv file into s3 bucket. Unfortunately/fortunately I get creds for being directly inside one. When I have checked what is inside it (using cloudberry) - I saw that there's nothing.

I'm using R's aws.s3 package.

Function:

```
s3write_using(tableData, 
              FUN = fwrite,
              bucket = "~/",
              object = "whatever.csv")
```

I get error:

```
 $ Code      : chr "InvalidBucketName"
 $ Message   : chr "The specified bucket is not valid."
```

It's quite clear for me, because there's no bucket there:D
Is there any way to omit bucket argument, and save the file?

In advance: 
No, I can't do it by hand. I want to push the code into jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in Amazon S3 must reside within a bucket.

In Cloudberry, you presumably looked for the file in a bucket. You should insert the same bucket name in your code.

Comment: I understand that all objects in s3 must reside within a bucket. But my creds give me permission for being inside bucket, and on the other hand argument "bucket" in s3write_using function require it. I cannot paste it there, because I'm inside it. I cannot paste name of the bucket that is above me. When I was pasting it, then I got error "Access Denied"

Comment: Credentials can be assigned **permissions** for accessing resources such as S3 buckets, but there is no such concept as credentials being inside a bucket. Credentials are associated with IAM Users, which are defined within an AWS Account.